# Form Validation and Submission to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, validation

I am working on a project that has a FORM which should VALIDATE itself and then submit the data to the MySQL Database. But I am facing an error.

This is the form

`

```
 <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">

    <table style="line-height: 50px;">
        <tr>
          <th>Name&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" style="height:30px; border:1px; width:300px; border-radius:5px; text-indent:15px"><span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <br>
        <tr>
          <th>Phone&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
          <td><input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Your Contact Number" style="height:30px; border:1px; width:300px; border-radius:5px; text-indent:15px"><span class="error">* <?php echo $contactErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>City&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
          <td><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Your City Name" style="height:30px; border:1px; width:300px; border-radius:5px; text-indent:15px"><span class="error">* <?php echo $cityErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Service&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
          <td><select name="service" autocomplete="off" style="height:30px; border:1px; width:300px; border-radius:5px; text-indent:15px">
              <option value="">Select your service</option>
              <option value=service1>Service 1</option>
              <option value=service2>Service 2</option>
              <option value=service3>Service 3</option>
              <option value=service4>Service 4</option>
              </select><span class="error">* <?php echo $serviceErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" style="height: 40px; width: 140px; border-radius: 5px; margin-left: 140px;margin-top: 20px;">
    </form>
```

`

And this is the VALIDATION SCRIPT

`

```
<?php 
    // define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $contactErr = $cityErr = $serviceErr = "";
$name = $contact = $city = $service = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["contact"])) {
     $contactErr = "Contact is required";
   } else {
     $contact = test_input($_POST["contact"]);
     // check if contact number is well-formed
     if (!preg_match("/^[0-9+]*$/",$contact)) {
       $contactErr = "Phone number should contain only numbers";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["city"])) {
     $cityErr = "City is required";
   } else {
     $city = test_input($_POST["city"]);
     // check if city is valid
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$city)) {
       $cityErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
     }
   }

   if (empty($_POST["service"])) {
     $serviceErr = "Service is required";
   } else {
     $service = test_input($_POST["service"]);
   }
 }

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

?>
```

`

This validates the form well but the PROBLEM that I am facing is to submit the form to the database after validation.

This is my upload_file.php code.

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="root"; // Mysql username 
$password="morningstar"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="infoline"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="user_profile"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$name=$_POST['name'];
$city=$_POST['city'];
$contact=$_POST['contact'];
$service=$_POST['service'];


// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO user_profile(name, city, contact, service)VALUES('$name', '$city', '$contact', '$service')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Can anyone help me solve the problem? I want to submit the form to the database after proper validation. Please help me out.

Comment: So, what's going wrong? Also, `mysql_*` is depreciated. You should look into using MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: Call your validation script if all else is ok

Comment: Show us what's the error.

Comment: @Yash Note: "This validates the form well but the PROBLEM that I am facing is to submit the form to the database after validation."

Comment: The error is that I am not being able to link the validation script and upload_file.php together. If I put the validation script in the upload_file.php page the data gets submitted without the execution of validation script. So I have to put the validation script to the same page where form exists i.e., index.php. Now what I actually want is after validation the form should be submitted to the database. This is where the problem occurs. Please help me.

Comment: First check print_r($_POST) method to check whether your data comes accurately or not.

Comment: @user3224929 it seems your validation part problem. if you use mozilla then install firebug add-ons and check whether your validation going wrong. It submit automatically when your validation have errors.

Answer (score 0):

IF I'm understanding this correctly, you just don't know how to call another file. I would suggest turning it into a function, including, and then calling it. Something like this:

```
include 'upload_file.php'

if($nameErr == $contactErr == $cityErr == $serviceErr == ""){
    upload_file($_POST['name'], $_POST['city'], $_POST['contact'], $_POST['service'])
}
```

Firstly note that I apologize for any syntax errors. That's freehand.

Second, there are a few things I would suggest for your code:

- Don't use the `mysql_*` functions, as they are depreciated. I like PDO, so that's what I'm going to suggest to look into. (Just Google it, plenty is out there) This will also allow you to use prepared statements, which is one of the biggest things the `mysql_*` functions are missing.
- Since you're using your POST data multiple times, place them into local variables to start. It will make your code short, cleaner, easier to read, and if you ever change the name of a field, must easier to update in the future.
- Place all errors into a single string. That way if it's successful, you only have to check one thing, and if it fails, you only have to send one thing back to the user.

Hope that's what you needed.

Comment: Should I include this in my validation file? I tried to do but it showed syntax error. Can you tell me where should I include it and how?

Comment: Yes, the upload script gets included into your validation script. I would assume at this point you have functionized your validation, as suggested, so what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Unexpected if on line 121... something like this. Can you please repost MY VALIDATION SCRIPT with YOUR piece of code in it so that it works correctly without any syntaxt errors. I will just copy and paste it then to make it work.

Comment: Assuming both scripts are in the same directory, you can copy paste exactly what I put at the bottom of your validation script. I believe the issue may have been a missing `$`, which I just fixed.